# Looking for a workaround for getrows

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Combobox providing data for a "filter" on a subform, once this subform has been filtered I'm using some code to enter the subform and put the data into an array.

I'm noticing that when I have more than 500 rows in my filtered data, getrows stops taking the data. (It's good from 0 to 500). Anything post 500 gives "" for the data.

I've tried increasing the getrows manually (instead of a variable I input like "1000"), and using ubound but I can't seem to get these to work how I would like them to. I assume their functionality isn't what I need.

```vb
Dim rstTooling As DAO.Recordset
Dim strToolingHolder() As \
Dim i As 
Dim intColumn As Integer, intRow As Integer, intHolder As Integer
Dim varRecords As Variant

i = 0
ReDim strToolingHolder(0)

Set rstTooling = Me.subTooling.Form.Recordset
intHolder = rstTooling.RecordCount
varRecords = rstTooling.GetRows(intHolder)

rstTooling.MoveLast
intHolder = rstTooling.RecordCount

For intColumn = 2 To 2
    For intRow = 0 To (intHolder - 1)
        strToolingHolder(i) = varRecords(intColumn, intRow)
        i = (i + 1)
        ReDim Preserve strToolingHolder(i)
    Next intRow
Next intColumn
```

I would ideally like to have varRecords (the getrows function) report back more than 500 data points. Although, if there are other ways that this can be done that may be better suited, I'm open to changing code around.

Comment: You may have to call `rstTooling.MoveLast` before retrieving the RecordCount.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I just went ahead and tried putting ```rstTooling.MoveLast``` before the first ```intHolder = rstTooling.RecordCount``` but unfortunately that breaks the code.

Comment: Then call `rstTooling.MoveFirst` next.

Comment: This is returning the same results post 500. I wonder if getrows has a (0 to 500) limitation. I do appreciate your input.

Comment: And what does `RecordCount` return? 500?

Comment: record count returns data over 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are missing, but this essential code:

```vb
Dim rstTooling  As DAO.Recordset
Dim intHolder   As Long
Dim varRecords  As Variant

Set rstTooling = Me.Recordset

rstTooling.MoveLast
intHolder = rstTooling.RecordCount
rstTooling.MoveFirst

varRecords = rstTooling.GetRows(intHolder)

Debug.Print LBound(varRecords, 2), UBound(varRecords, 2)
```

returns correctly and as expected for a table of 200000 records:

```
0    199999
```

Comment: Ah, adding the ```rstTooling.MoveFirst``` after the intholder made a big difference, this works perfectly now. 

Thank you very much!